# ESRI : 54019 or World winkel II in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Currently I didn't find World winkel II or ESRI : 54019 coordinate system support in qgis. One of our client using this.. Can any one tell me a solution to load shape files,which are using his coordinate system. I didn't find .proj4 file for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can not use that projection in QGIS.

QGIS is based on GDAL, but that does not know winkel II either. Only Proj knows a projection definition +proj=wink2. But it has no support for the inverse projection.

According to this similar question on Winkel tripel:

[How to reproject a raster to Winkel Tripel projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37721/how-to-reproject-a-raster-to-winkel-tripel-projection)

the projection can not get implemented into GDAL and QGIS if there is no inverse projection defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, only ARCGIS has that support. Is there any other tool has that support.

Comment: I have not found any. It would be easier to reproject the data inside ARCGIS to a projection that both systems can work with.